# How to do Refresh a web page when user turns mobile to landscape

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am doing a web application for android and iPhone. My problem is, i want to do refresh the webpage, when user goes to landscape. Since i'm a beginner in javascript i don't know how to do this. please help me

Comment: There exists an question like this and an answer ;)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850472/how-do-i-detect-when-the-iphone-goes-into-landscape-mode-via-javascript-is-ther

Comment: please close this question to avoid duplicates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [orientationchange](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/#docs/api/events.html) jQuery Mobile event and then do a

```
window.location.reload();
```

to refresh the page.

For example:

```
$(function(){

// Set Inital orientation
// get the initial orientation from window which
// returns 0 for portrait and 1 for landscape
if(window.orientation == 0){
    var ori = "portrait";
}else{
    var ori = "landscape";
}
changeOrientation(ori);

// Orientation Change
// When orientation changes event is triggered
// exposing an orientation property of either
// landscape or portrait
$('body').bind('orientationchange',function(event){
    changeOrientation(event.orientation)
})

// Change the style dependengt on orientation
function changeOrientation(ori){
    // Remove all classes separated by spaces
    $("#orientation").removeClass('portrait landscape');
    $("#orientation").addClass(ori);
    $("#orientation").html("<p>"+ori.toUpperCase()+"</p>");
}

});
```

Comment: I used your code like this, still not works "<body orientationchange="window.location.reload();">"

Comment: @yuzi I've updated my code, but i suggest you take a look in to jquery and jquery mobile (which this example is using)

Comment: finally i did like this,
 then it works
" window.onorientationchange = function() {
  var orientation = window.orientation;
  switch(orientation) {
    case 0:
        window.location.reload(); 
        break; 
    case 90:
         window.location.reload(); 
         break;
    case -90: 
         window.location.reload(); 
         break;
  }
}"
thanks Johan

Answer (score 0):

You could use a timer and periodically check:

```
if (window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth) {
    // Redirect code, window.location...
}
```

Comment: If height > width, the mobile would be in portrait mode, not landscape