# JQuery mobile: redraw whole page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have some dinamic layout in may JQuery mobile \ phonegap application. I test HTML in `iframe`. It's normal in `iframe`. When I open it at android phone layout is breaks, but after oreinetation changed layout becomes normal. So, I read JQuery mobile code realted to `orientationchange` event but did not found anything useful. How can I force android\jquery mobile to redraw page like after `orientationchange`. I tried `$page.trigger( "create");` and etc but it didnt help

### Update

```
<script lang="javascript">
    function calcBlockSizes() {
        $.each($('[data-role=page]'), function(i, page){
            $page = $(page);
            var bodyfixed = $page.find(".bodyfixed");
            var topfixed = $page.find(".topfixed:first");
            var bottomfixed = $page.find(".bottomfixed:first");
            if ($(".topfixed").length > 0) {
                bodyfixed.css("top", topfixed.outerHeight() + 'px');
            } else {
                bodyfixed.css("top", "0px");
            }
            if ($(".bottomfixed").length > 0) {
                bodyfixed.css("bottom", bottomfixed.outerHeight() + 'px');
            } else {
                bodyfixed.css("bottom", "0px");
            }
            $page.trigger( "create");
        });

    }
    $(window).load(function() {
        calcBlockSizes();
    });
    //$(document).delegate('.ui-page', 'pageshow', function () {
    //    calcBlockSizes();
    //});
</script>
```

Problem is `topfixed` div not looks like `css("top", "0px");` same with bottom. They are at incorrect postions - something wrong with `top` and `bottom` values. But I didn't know how to test it inside phonegap app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do Refresh a web page when user turns mobile to landscape](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848576/how-to-do-refresh-a-web-page-when-user-turns-mobile-to-landscape)

Comment: No. Your question is identical to the link above. Use orientationchange and window.location.reload();

Comment: I' dont need to reload page (possible lose some information). I need to _redraw_ it, like phonegap do it after orientation change. I changed title of question. And I don't think thats it's good idea to `window.location.reload()` in Jquery mobile - "pages" are `div`s in same HTML file