# JavaScript resize event on scroll - mobile

Tags: javascript, events, mobile, resize

I'm trying to make a website for mobile. I'm having the "resize" event bounded on window, which should rearrange elements when the mobile device is turning (portrait <-> landscape). On iPhone and Samsung Galaxy SII, the event is triggered when I'm scrolling down the page, and that's not good.

How can I fix this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/8898412/89818

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `onOrientationChange` event and the `window.orientation` property instead.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/850475/843985).

Here link [to a test page](http://jsfiddle.net/BvMHu/show/).

Answer (score 54):

Cache the width of the viewport and on resize return false if the width is still the same.

A small jQuery snippet:

```
    var cachedWidth = $(window).width();
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var newWidth = $(window).width();
        if(newWidth !== cachedWidth){
            //DO RESIZE HERE
            cachedWidth = newWidth;
        }
    });
```

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for. So nice. OP This should be the accepted answer. This is the correct way to go about it.

Comment: @LukeFlego it is the best way to fix this bug, not ideal code though. Sometimes the easiest fix is the best :)

Comment: Ran into the same issue, and this fixed it. This is the correct answer.

Comment: This looks like jQuery and there's nothing about it in the question.. but thank you, sidonaldson, for the answer – not bad at all.

Comment: @LGT correct. I'll update the answer to make that clear

Comment: `window.innerWidth` for all wanting the jQuery free answer.