# Mobile scroll fires jQuery resize event - (it only fires when using mobile, ok in browser viewport)

Tags: jquery, mobile, resize

> This is my code here it works fine on browser but not on mobile, am
>   not that expert in jQuery so if there is any mistake, do forgive me.ty

```
var width = $(window).width(), height = $(window).height();
            $(window).on('resize', function() {

                if($(window).width() != width && $(window).height() != height)
                {
                    var width = $(window).width(), height = $(window).height();

                    //do something here;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Many mobile browsers (at least Chrome and Safari) hide or show or resize their menu bar when scrolling up or down, which effectively resizes the `window`.

Comment: First of all thank you for your replay...So thats the issue am facing, in your opinion will this be avoided using only "width of the Window" as the trigger?@MyronHöster

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript resize event on scroll - mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361968/javascript-resize-event-on-scroll-mobile)

Comment: ok Got it, ty for your tip. Actually i used the code on the answer and it worked like a charm. TY for you listening to my Q

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out the answer in **StackOverflow** itself [link of the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361968/javascript-resize-event-on-scroll-mobile). it's the answer by ***`sidonaldson`*** that helped me solve my issue.ty

Here is the code

```
var cachedWidth = $(window).width();
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var newWidth = $(window).width();
        if(newWidth !== cachedWidth){
            //DO RESIZE HERE
            cachedWidth = newWidth;
        }
    });
```