# JQuery window.location.reload() reload while scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developping a website for handheld devices (smartphones and tablets), and I have a JQuery animation. I needed to reload the JS if the device change orientation so I found and used :

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
     window.location.reload();
});
```

But the pages reload on page scroll without changing orientation, same in Chrome with developer tools without changing size.

Is there a solution or a way to reload the JS without `window.location.reload();` ?

Comment: Change position meaning from `landscape` to `portrait`?

Comment: You should probably have a look at the `orientationchange` event and go from there.

Comment: Its a known issue in mobile or tablet (I guess) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361968/javascript-resize-event-on-scroll-mobile

Comment: @RobertUdah Indeed it's a duplicate, didn't saw it.