# Detect scroll in mobile Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

Im trying to do an animation when a user scrolls a page. I'm using `window.pageYOffset`.  In Safari it works as soon as scroll starts, but in Chrome it will only detect the scroll after touch end. How can I detect scrolling while its happening, not at the very end?

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
   var distanceY = window.pageYOffset
   if (distanceY > 0) {
      DO STUFF
   }
});
```

This functions alright on desktop browsers and mobile Safari, but not in mobile Chrome.

Here is the [tutorial](http://callmenick.com/_development/resize-header-on-scroll/) that I was using, it has this problem as well - in mobile Safari the animation would happen when the screen is scrolled just to the second paragraph, but in Chrome it will stay static until touch end.

Comment: As far as I know many mobile browsers freeze any rendering/script execution during a scroll because redrawing while scrolling can be super intensive, depending on how far and fast you're scrolling.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this code below:

```
$('window').on('touchmove', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault(); 

    var distanceY = window.pageYOffset
    if (distanceY > 0) {
     // DO STUFF
    }
});
```

Also because of some reason Chrome fires window.resize event on scroll. You can find the issue on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17328742/mobile-chrome-fires-resize-event-on-scroll).