# Why a React app freezes on mobile devices?

Tags: reactjs, mobile, react-router, crash

I made a small app using react and it works smoothly on my computer. However, when I open it on different mobile devices it crashes after a minute or so of usage. I don't know what causes the problem but weirdly enough I don't have any bugs or warnings on my console and haven't used componentDidUpdate or hooks that might cause infinite loops like useEffect. Please help me if you know what causes a react app to glitch on mobile devices or have encountered the same problem and found a solution for it.
Here's the app

https://summerresort.netlify.app

and the code

https://github.com/Mahmoud-farargy/summerresort/tree/master/Beach-Resort

Thanks!

Comment: which mobile devices do you see this crashes?

Comment: On different Samsung smartphones like note 3 and J7 core.

Comment: does it crash while using or crashes when opening?

Comment: only when using it

Comment: You can use it yourself and see if you will experience the same thing I'm having.

Comment: Anyways, you might be missing some polyfills. Trying putting [this](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) in your app and see if it works.

Comment: @PrãtéékThápá could you explain more about the polyfills

Comment: @MahmoudFarargy It has no issues on my Samsung Galaxy J8, did you fix it if yes then could you explain how.

Comment: @Rupesh Chaudhari I don't think it has fixed completely but I did install a polyfills package to my project and removed the notification feature, they reduced the glitchiness of the app a little bit but it still crashes at some point. I went through my old deploys on Netlify and found some good versions that don't crash at all but unfortunately, I can't reuse them since the site gives you only minified code so they are unreusable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app looks all ok except 2 points. I can't test my guess, but I'm almost entirely sure that your problem comes from those 2.

Both parts that seem problematic are located in `index.js`, here there are:

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {// gets the current height
    let  scroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    let arrowUp = document.querySelector(".arrow-up-btn").style;
    scroll >= 1000 ? arrowUp.display="flex" : arrowUp.display = "none";
});

window.addEventListener("resize", ()=> {// gets the current width
    this.setState({
        currentPageWidth: window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth
    })
});
```

The first code block is expensive because:

1. [The scroll event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event) is fired **very** frequently.
2. You don't [listen for scroll passively](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/passive-event-listeners) (it'd be a good idea though).
3. You set the `style` much more frequently than needed.

However, I think, that it is the second code block that causes mobiles to glitch.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27966414/9430588) to see why [the resize event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event) is fired on mobiles more frequently than on desktop.

1. Now, each time the resize event is triggered, the state of `MainApp`
   is updated.
2. Each time `MainApp` is updated, React recalculates all its children.
3. By default, React just re-run render of each child & compares the output.

Considering you have all routes & all components inside the `MainApp` & you didn't implement any optimizations (`React.PureComponent`, lazy loading for routes, etc.) React will have to recalculate what the entire site looks like on each `resize` event.

The easiest fix would be to store `currentPageWidth` in [a ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) instead of state.

Another possible problem is that by attaching listeners inside the render method, you're attaching new listeners on **each single render** without clearing any of previously added listeners.

Comment: Yeah, dude, I figured that out a while ago the main problem was with the resize event which caused the app to clitch while not throwing an error after I removed it the app runs very smoothly. So moral of the story, don't use the resize event except when it necessary and always keep a copy of your app on another place or use Git so whenever you encounter a problem with your app you'll find old versions to fall back into.

Comment: And you were right about React.PureComponent. I should have used it to block most components from re-rendering unnecessarily.